# Query gives 1 on null values

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two tables containing artists(artist) and countries(country), I'm trying to join the two tables and i want to display the countries that have 0 artists (countries that are not at all in the artist table). This query gives me all the artists, but instead of "0" in the row with countries that have 0 artists it gives "1". Do i need to specify it somewhere what value it should give in case it is null?

```
SELECT   c.country_name AS shteti, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM   country c
left outer join artist a
ON  c.countryID = a.FK_countryID 
GROUP BY c.country_name

so it gives Andorra 1, even though Andorra is not at all in the Artist 
table.

"Albania"   "5"
"Andorra"   "1"
"Argentina" "2"
```

Comment: The left join ensures there will be at least one row per country, hence the count always being at least 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT(a.FK_countryID)` instead. This counts only non-null entries, while `COUNT(*)` counts the rows, no matter whether a column is null or not.

`COUNT(a.FK_countryID)` will yield the exact number of artists from that country, including 0.

Since you are using a LEFT JOIN, Your query will return a row with a country name but a NULL entry for FK_countryID when there is no matching artist.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `left join`, and get only the rows where `a.FK_countryID IS NULL`

```
SELECT   c.country_name AS shteti, 0 AS count
FROM   country c
left join artist a
ON  c.countryID = a.FK_countryID 
WHERE a.FK_countryID IS NULL
```

This gives you all the countries not present in the artist table.
I left `0` as 2nd column but it is not needed.